# explorer on Google Chart does not work - Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer, google-visualization

I'm using the google-chart web components but the explorer (that allow zooming in and out) does not work. Here is the code :

```js
options: {
    type:Array,
    value:{
        title: 'Today Consumption',
        curveType: 'function',

        chartArea:{
            backgroundColor: '#E2E8ED',
            height: 300,
            width: 650,
        },
        explorer: {
            axis: 'horizontal',
            keepInBounds: true,
            maxZoomIn: 4.0
        },
        height: 400,
        width: 830,
        backgroundColor:'#E2E8ED',
        colors:["#4882A8"]}
    }
},
```

```html
<google-chart type="line" options='{{options}}' data='{{chartData}}'></google-chart>
```

It looks like that :
  [image: Chart]
But I'm unable to zoom in or out..? Does someone have an idea of why it doesn't work?

Comment: please share a sample of the data, what is the data type of the x-axis? `explorer` only works with continuous axes (such as numbers or dates)

Comment: thanks for the answer, the data look like :
[['Time', 'Watt'], ["2h19m", 416]]. So the problem comes from the fact that my date is actually a built String ?

Comment: Edit:
I tried to replace it with  : `moment(val[0]).format('HH:mm')` but it doesn't work

Comment: Thanks for the lead i'll have to dig it up when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

explorer only works with continuous axes (such as numbers, dates or timeofday)

for the x-axis, use type --> `'timeofday'`
which should be an array with 3-4 elements...

```
[hour, min, second]
[hour, min, second, milli]
```

the following should convert your string values to a valid `'timeofday'`

```
var timeStr = '2h19m';
var hour = timeStr.split('h');
var min = hour[1].split('m');
var timeArr = [parseInt(hour[0]), parseInt(min[0]), 0];
```

Comment: Gonna try soon i'll tell you